# How to include a .so lib using cmake

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, cmake, linux-mint

I am retired and been away from programming for several years.  I am writing an application that stores all its info in XML files.  I am using vscode and cmake under linux mint for building. It is big enough now that I want to run it through doxygen to see all the relationships.

I'm using leethomason/tinyxml2 from github to read/write/access my XML for the project.  (A very nice lightweight XML lib, BTW.) Since it only consistes of a single header and source file I have been just compilling them with my code. But the doxygen docs show all the interelationships within tinyxml which is distracting for my purpose. So it is time to break it out into its on lib.

I can build the tinyxml github clone fine. It generates a libtinyxml2d.so, a cmake_install.cmake and cmake_uninstall.cmake (and all the other stuff) in the build directory.  What I cannot figure out how to do is to tell my project cmake file how to include the lib.

The tinyxml2 CMakeLists.txt file says:

```
# Export cmake script that can be used by downstream project
# via `include()`
export(TARGETS tinyxml2
      FILE ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/${TARGETS_EXPORT_NAME}.cmake)

install(TARGETS tinyxml2
        EXPORT ${TARGETS_EXPORT_NAME}
        RUNTIME 
                DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_BINDIR}
                COMPONENT tinyxml2_runtime
        LIBRARY 
                DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}
                COMPONENT tinyxml2_libraries
        ARCHIVE 
                DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}
                COMPONENT tinyxml2_libraries)
```

But I cannot figure out how to use that info to link the lib into my cmake file.  I search and read the documentation but that is like reading a foreign language because of all the stuff I've forgotten or never knew. (cmake, linux and vscode are all new worlds for me.)
Can someone give an old guy a few pointers? Where to look for examples that are not rudimentary "how to use cmake", or tutorials for lib installation/access.

Thanks,

Eddie

Comment: Have you looked into target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE <library_name>). Or just search target_link_libraries

Answer (score 0):

Well, I succeeded but I feel really dumb for it.
I did some more poking around and found how to use the install file.
I did:

```
cmake -P cmake_install.cmake
```

which copied it to the system directory like I wanted then simply added the lib name to the target command in the cmake file.
Turns out that wasn't the problem I was trying to cure.
I forgot to remove the tinyxml cpp ad h files from the directory that doxygen was using.

Well, Duh...

Eddie

Comment: You don't need to call the install script directly.. Use `cmake --install <build-dir> [--prefix <local-install-prefix>]`. If you set a <local-install-prefix>, you can add it to the CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH of your project at the command line so you don't have to install it systemwide.

Comment: And you should definitely do a `find_package(tinyxml2 REQUIRED)` and then `target_link_libraries(myapp PRIVATE tinyxml2)` rather than linking to the library file (linking to an exported target like this automatically sets up include paths, too, ideally)